# HTML: Making over-writable textbox value.Like Facebook sign-up text boxes?

Tags: html

This text box property is not over-writable. It needs to delete the default value by backspace or select and delete. So how to make it over-writable?

```
<form action="demo_form.asp">
  First name: <input type="text" name="fname" value="first name"><br>
  Last name: <input type="text" name="lname" value="last name"><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Please give an example of this in the web. Facebook does not show it for me. Then have a look at the page's html source code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"`placeholder`" can do the trick:

```
<form action="demo_form.asp">
    First name: <input type="text" name="fname" placeholder="first name"><br>
    Last name: <input type="text" name="lname" placeholder="last name"><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```